# How to make a UISplitViewController in portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to make a UISplitViewController in portrait mode just like in the Settings app. How can I do it?

Comment: Duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631672/ipad-splitviewcontroller-with-menu-in-portrait-mode-like-settings-app

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to try this method http://blog.blackwhale.at/2010/04/your-first-ipad-split-view-application/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPad SplitViewController with menu in portrait mode like settings app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631672/ipad-splitviewcontroller-with-menu-in-portrait-mode-like-settings-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit late, but also take a look at the [MGSplitViewController](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) by Matt Gemmel. It does what you need and so much more. It's what UISplitViewController should be, and it's a snap to implement.

Answer (score 1):

From the UISplitViewController class documentation:

> A split view controller supports the
>   same interface orientations as its
>   currently visible child view
>   controllers. Both view controllers are
>   displayed in landscape orientations
>   but ***only the detail view controller is
>   displayed in portrait orientations.***
>   When transitioning between
>   orientations, the split view
>   controller sends messages to its
>   delegate object to coordinate the
>   display of a popover with the hidden
>   view controller. For more information
>   on the methods of this delegate
>   object, see
>   UISplitViewControllerDelegate Protocol
>   Reference.

(Emphesis added.)

Comment: The settings app isn't a split view controller.  It's an awful mess of black-magic and it's not clear to me that Apple would allow an app that did that into the store.  Caveat Developor!  ;)

Comment: Yes, but this isn't helpful. OP cites a totally reasonably example of a UI that has a split portrait view and asks how to accomplish it. Saying "it's impossible" argues with the evidence, even if the technique is either undocumented or must be built from scratch.

Comment: There is no evidence of a UISplitViewController in portrait mode -- that's what I'm saying.  It's done with javascript and it's a terrible mess.

And my answer IS helpful because if OP is thinking of submitting such an app, it is likely to get rejected.  "Non standard UI", and all that.

(Yes, yes, I understand the hypocrisy.)

I'll try to find the link to the how-to-do-it in js & post it, but "you'll be sorry!"  ;)

Comment: Heh, in searching for the OTHER url, I ran across this SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631672/ipad-splitviewcontroller-with-menu-in-portrait-mode-like-settings-app

Which has a good answer, including sample code.