# The controller in the left pane of the iPad Settings Application

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder

Does anyone know what view/controller do I have to use to obtain the same look as the Settings application on iPad has in the left pane. Without using the splitviewcontroller that is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad SplitViewController with menu in portrait mode like settings app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631672/ipad-splitviewcontroller-with-menu-in-portrait-mode-like-settings-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bizarrely there is no standard control to do it. There is, however, an open source component that you can use: [MGSplitViewController](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController).

Comment: @priyanka I think that's relevant to the question but not my answer. I've added my vote to close this question, noting the question you note as the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Someone created a custom class that does that. Take a look at [APSplitViewController](https://github.com/slatvick/APSplitViewController).