# UISplitView - Mimic portrait mode in landscape

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Is it possible to setup the UISplitViewController to work in landscape mode the same way as it does in portrait? e.g the details view takes the full screen with the master view contained in the popover.

The added complexity my layout has is that the details view on the right is contained within a navigation controller so the one or two examples I've seen of this don't seem to work.

**EDIT:** I only need full-screen on one of the views in my detail view. It's showing photo's and they want to be able to see them full screen in landscape.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631672/ipad-splitviewcontroller-with-menu-in-portrait-mode-like-settings-app) Q&A on SO, the same problem, solution is vague.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have a split view then? you can just have a normal view with a toolbar or a navigation bar, with a bar button item, which displays a pop over.

Comment: Fair point and if I had the time to start from scratch I probably would.

Comment: I've clarified what I'm looking for by editing my post above.