# iPad - Locking a UISplitviewController so both views say split

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'd like to keep the `UISplitViewController`'s "split"ness active in landscape or portrait, much like the "settings" on the iPad. Is there a way to do this? I don't see anything in the class documentation that allows this.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631672/ipad-splitviewcontroller-with-menu-in-portrait-mode-like-settings-app