# How to force master view open in master-detail app

Tags: ios, swift, master-detail

Is there a way to force the master pane open at all times (app is iPad only so namely the portrait mode) in a master-detail application using Swift? I understand I can swipe right from the left side to get the master view, but I'd like to just have it there all the time.

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631672/ipad-splitviewcontroller-with-menu-in-portrait-mode-like-settings-app

Comment: Yep that's it. Thank you!